# Ruby Project Euler 35-Circular Primes Wrong Answer

Tags: ruby

I tried [Project Euler question 35](https://projecteuler.net/problem=35) in Ruby (I am quite new to it) and got the wrong answer.

The problem:

> The number, 197, is called a circular prime because all rotations of
>   the digits: 197, 971, and 719, are themselves prime.
>
> There are thirteen such primes below 100: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 31,
>   37, 71, 73, 79, and 97.
>
> How many circular primes are there below one million?

My code:

```
require 'prime'

def primes(n)
  nums = [nil, nil, *2..n]
  (2..Math.sqrt(n)).each do |i|
    (i**2..n).step(i) { |m| nums[m] = nil } if nums[i]
  end
  nums.compact
end

prime = primes(1000000)    
circularPrimes = 0

prime.each do |j|
  puts "\n"
  puts j
  flag = false
  j = j.to_s()
  for k in (0..j.length)
    temp = j[k..-1] + j[0..k]
    temp = temp.to_i()
    a = Prime.prime?(temp)
    if a == false then
      flag = true
      break
    end
  end

  if flag == false then
    circularPrimes += 1
  end
end  

puts"\n\n\n\n\n"

puts circularPrimes
```

I can't figure out the problem in the code (which I think is fine).

Comment: Side note: instead of generating the primes yourself, you can just do `Prime.each(1_000_000)`

Comment: Yeah but what about the answer

Comment: Please describe what your current output is and why you think it's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-inventing two things:

- generating primes upto n (use `Prime.each(n)`)
- rotating the digits (use `Array#rotate!`)

Probably the problem is somewhere in there. I would do it this way:

```
require 'prime'

def rotations(x)
  digits = x.to_s.chars
  digits.map do
    digits.rotate!.join.to_i
  end
end

circular_primes = Prime.each(1_000_000).select do |p|
  rotations(p).all?{|r| Prime.prime?(r) }
end

puts circular_primes.count
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your rotation is off by 1, trying

```
j="123456"
j[1..-1] + j[0..1]    # that is k=1 from the above code
```

yields

```
"2345612"
```

which would not be a rotation. Could be fixed through

```
temp = j[k..-1] + j[0...k]
```

Comment: This still doesn't yield the correct result for n = 100.

Comment: @Cupcake correct, but `k=j.length` should not be there in the first place. @Bhavya should either iterate through `0...j.length` or `1..j.length` and adjust the rotation code accordingly (mine will work for the former).

Comment: What about when `k = 0`? Then `j[0..k-1]` becomes `j[0..-1]`, which ends up doubling the string instead of rotating it. I think you just need to exclude the end of the range for the operations/math to work out, like this: `j[0...k]`.

Comment: Again you are right. Probably this whole business of generating all  the rotations from scratch is more difficult than it should be. It should be possible to just rotate the first character to the last one `n-1` times (that would make it something like `str=str[1..-1]+str[0]`). I fixed the answer to reflect your input.

Comment: No, you're right about starting the iteration from `1` instead of `0`, that makes it so that you don't generate a rotation that you already have, the initial one. You're also right that it's tricky doing it from scratch. Ruby actually has a `rotate` method, but it's only defined on arrays, not on strings :(

Answer (score 1):

As Patru mentioned, your rotation was not right. I am not sure about your `primes` method either, though I did not try to fix it. Since you are not opposed to using the `Prime` class, I instead used that for a solution which is easier on the eyes, and correct as far as I can tell. Though it seems to perform quite badly, perhaps it can be optimized. It will return an answer for `1_000_000`, but it takes about 70 seconds which seems awfully long.

I suppose instead of going through all numbers I should at least skip all rotations I already processed and determined were circular prime or not. Anyway, now you'll have some optimizing to do.

```
require 'prime'

def circular_prime?(n)
  rotations(n).all? { |r| Prime.prime? r }
end

def rotations(n)
  str = n.to_s
  (0...str.length).map do |i|
    (str[i..-1] + str[0...i]).to_i
  end
end

(2 .. 100).select { |n| circular_prime?(n) }
# => [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 31, 37, 71, 73, 79, 97]
```

Incorporating your `primes` method, you can change the circular prime generation to

```
primes(1_000_000).select { |prime| circular_prime? prime }
```

The behavior is equivalent to your code in that it first selects all primes up to a million and then selects the circular primes from there. A slight optimization would be to remove the original number from the rotations to be checked, since we already know it is prime.

The single timing I did yielded 50 seconds for this variant so this at least seems faster than my original (~70 sec), which is not really surprising since I went through all rotations of all numbers between 2 and 1 million, whereas by first selecting primes the input to `rotations` is significantly reduced.

Comment: The `primes` method is correct, I tested it against the results from Ruby's `Prime` sequence.

Comment: You can also use `(0...s.length).map { |i| s.split('').rotate(i).join }` to generate the rotations, but your method is pretty simple too, so I would consider keeping it.

Comment: Speed up: except for primes 2 and 5, the primes can not have any other digits than 1,3,7,9. All other digits would appear at the end of the number, making it non-prime.

Comment: @steenslag Interesting. There are probably more properties like that or other prime related tricks which can be taken advantage of to do this a lot more efficiently.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers also, when you generate rotations, you start the iteration from 0 instead of 1, doesn't that give you an extra rotation that you don't actually need to test (the initial string)?

Comment: @Cupcake Yes, you are right. I mentioned that optimization too (*A slight optimization would be to remove the original number from the rotations to be checked since we already know it is prime*), but did not adjust `rotations` to reflect that in my original code. Rotations was implemented that way because my first method would require it, as it did not select all primes between 1 and 1 million at the start, so it had to check the initial string as well. But changing the loop to `(1...str.length)` would be better for the variant doing `primes(1_000_000)` first indeed.

Comment: how do i remove the elements from the l;s